# Xpath get element with condition

Tags: html, dom, xpath

I have some block of code and need to get data out of it and trying different version of xpath commands but with no success.

```
<div>
    <div class="some_class">
        <a title="id" href="some_href">
            <nobr>1<br>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="some_other_class">
        <a title="name" href="some_href">
            <nobr>John<br>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="some_class">
        <a title="id" href="some_href">
            <nobr>2<br>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="some_other_class">
        <a title="name" href="some_href">
            <nobr>John<br>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

// and many blocks like this
```

So, this div blocks are the same except they are different by content of its sub-element. I need xpath query to get John's href which `<a title="id">` is equal to 1.

I've tried something like this:

```
//div[./div/nobr='1' AND ./div/nobr='John']
```

to get only div that contains data I need and then wouldn't be hard to get John's href.

Also, I've managed to get John's href with:

```
//a[./nobr='John'][@title='name']/@href
```

but that way it doesn't depend on value from `<a title="id"...>` element but it has to depend on it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you want to get "John's href", why don't you create an example where John's href is different than the other `href` attributes so you can clearly express what you want?

Comment: Also, be aware that XPath is defined only on well-formed markup, which your example is not: There are multiple root elements and multiple unclosed elements.

Comment: It isn't about href, I've clearly said I need href which is inside of "super-element" of John, i.e. <nobr>John</nobr> is sub-element of <a> tag that has href attribute I need. Unclosed element <nobr> is a typo. Thank you for your generous petty remarks :)

Comment: Sorry, had you truly said anything clearly, we would have answered your question for you by now.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you want is

```
//div/div[a/@title='id']/following-sibling::div[1]/a/@href
```

which, given a well-formed input document, will return (individual results separated by `--------`):

```
href="some_href"
-----------------------
href="some_href"
```

You did not explain it very clearly though, as kjhughes has noted, and perhaps your sample HTML is not ideal.

Regarding your attempted path expressions, as the input is HTML, it is hard to know whether

```
<nobr>John<br>
```

means that "John" is *inside* the `nobr` element or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mathias, your example was helpful, but as there are many  elements with @title='id' it isn't reliable solution that will always catch good elements.

I've managed to make workaround, first catched the whole div, and then extract href I need.

```
//div[./div/a[@title='name']/nobr='John' and ./div/a[@title='id']/nobr='1'] 
//a[./nobr='John'][@title='name']/@href
```